# Asp.net web app not displaying on client workstations

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, sharepoint-2010

I started to ask this question already but I think I may need to reword it.  I have an asp.net web application I built in VS2010 that is published to our Sharepoint site. This site is basically a form for doing employee status change requests and I need it to populate drop down boxes from an active directory query.  I have set this all up and works fantastically...on our server but when I go to access the site on a workstation I get an instance error and throws a null reference.  It looks like its telling me it is not running the active directory query methods.

Here is the error:

```
    Server Error in '/Requests' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable dataSource) +562
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.PerformSelect() +48
   RequestForm._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1464
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +24
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +41
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +131
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +65
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2427
```

Here is the adquery which basic basically just loads up a list:

```
 public PreLoadForm()
        {
            //empty constructor calls the search method when class is instantiated
            ADSearch();
            //and sorts the array
            SortList(groups);
        }


        public string[] Groups //property to pass the groups array over to the calling class
        {
            get
            {
                return groups;
            }
        }


        protected void ADSearch()
        {
            //The Active Directory Search

            int x; //index variable for loading array

            domainName = "******"; //the domain

            theQuery = "(&(objectClass=group)(description=branch*))"; //the query statement

            groups = new string[14]; //instantiating the groups array

            #region
            theEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=" + domainName + ", DC=***", "*******", "*********"); //LDAP entry
            #endregion
            theSearch = new DirectorySearcher(theEntry); //new search of the directory using the entry to connect

            theSearch.Filter = theQuery; //use our query statement for a search filter

            theSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name"); //the value we want back from the search

            try
            {
                //assign the the search findings to a results collection
                mySearchResultColl = theSearch.FindAll();
            }
            catch
            {

            }


            x = 0;

            try
            {
                //loop through the search results
                foreach (SearchResult sr in mySearchResultColl)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry de = sr.GetDirectoryEntry(); //assign the search entries to a directory entry
                    groups[x] = de.Properties["name"].Value.ToString(); //assign the desired value to the array
                    x++; //increment the index

                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

The page load:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //when the form loads, instantiate the preLoadForm
            LoadForm = new PreLoadForm();

            unselectedArray = new string[numOfOffices]; //instantiate the unselected array

            unselectedArray = LoadForm.Groups; //and load the array from Active Directory

            if (!Page.IsPostBack) //if page has not be reloaded
            {
                //disable certain entries until selected
                officesDropDownList.Enabled = false;
                equipDropDownList.Enabled = false;
                positionTextBox.Enabled = false;
                managerTextBox.Enabled = false;
                terminationTextBox.Enabled = false;
                pcCheckBox.Enabled = false;
                laptopCheckBox.Enabled = false;


                for (int x = 0; x < numOfOffices; x++) //loop the number of times we have offices
                {
                    removeListBox.Items.Add(unselectedArray[x]); //populate the remove list box with the unselected arrarry
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < LoadForm.EmailGroups.Count; i++) //similar loop for populating email list box
                {
                    removeEmailListBox.Items.Add(LoadForm.EmailGroups.ElementAt<string>(i)); //populate from a list
                    //due to the unkown size nature of the email groups
                }

                try
                {
                    officesDropDownList.DataSource = unselectedArray; //quick and dirty way to load the drop down list with our offices
                    officesDropDownList.DataBind();
                    equipDropDownList.DataSource = unselectedArray; //used to be LoadForm.Groups
                    equipDropDownList.DataBind();
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException exceptEx)
                {
                    string messageString = exceptEx.ToString();
                    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>" + messageString + "</script>");
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you post some code please? It could be because the AD query is using the user's creds and the request is getting denied.

Answer (score 0):

Trying my best to follow your code here.
First the stack trace shows the call gets past on line 1464

```
RequestForm._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1464
```

I'll just assume you took out the additional lines for brevity, but it is a lot of code to put into a page load.

These two lines are redundant:

```
unselectedArray = new string[numOfOffices]; //instantiate the unselected array
unselectedArray = LoadForm.Groups; //and load the array from Active Directory
```

`unselectedArray` will just get replace with whatever is returned by `LoadForm.Groups`
which looks like it gets populated from `PreLoadForm.ADSearch()` which gives `Groups` a value. I'm curious how you came up with 14? Why not just use `List<string>` ?

My suggestion would be to not have the two blocks of try...catch where you are swallowing exceptions. This is bad practice. Find out if and why exceptions are being thrown there. That will probably get you closer to your issue.

Comment: with it working on the server side and not on client side, does the exceptioin have anything to do with my problem? I am more apt to believe this is a configuration issue in publishing out to sharepoint?

Comment: That may be true, but I would guess an exception is being thrown when invoked from the client.

Comment: Yeah I am unsure why it shows line 1464...what you see for my page_load is what is there. The codes not optmized, I orginally was passing an array but it wasn't working with the databind so I switched to a list and never took out the instantiation.  Took out the try blocks but still getting the same error message

Comment: Is `numOfOffices` always 14 or less?

Comment: Can you ensure that `LoadForm.EmailGroups` is never null?

Comment: thats also why I switched to lists, so numOffices isn't used.  As long as we don't delete offices out of AD, it shouldn't ever be null. I know the null reference comes from the AD query not happening but what I don't know is why? Because when I access the site from our sharepoint server it pulls up and the dropdrowns are populated, but for some reason this isn't happening when I pull the site up on a client.  Which is where I think "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." is my problem but I don't know where this is stemming from and why